# Compute engine instance went missing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I set up a compute engine instance some time in October 2017.
Yesterday (25 April 2018) I'm surprised to find out the instance I setup went missing.

Looking at the Activity Stream there is no record of the VM instance being deleted explicitly.

The last record that I can find in the activity stream that hinted the VM instance existed at all was an entry that says "Resolved: Underutilised VM Instance"

[image]

That was on February 2018. After that, the VM instance has simply vanished.

Anyone has a similar experience to this? What do you think could have happened between February and April 2018 that would cause this?

Comment: Was it a trial? VM instances disappear once your trial period is over, please specify if it was a trial.

Comment: It wasn't on trial when it was created. I'm pretty sure billing was enabled that time. Does the scenario you just outlined applies too in case of declined payments (there was an issue with bank or credit card for example)?

Comment: Yes, it's possible: "*If your billing account remains invalid for a protracted period, some resources might be removed from the projects associated with your account. For example, if you use Google Cloud Platform, your Google Compute Engine resources might be removed. Removed resources are not recoverable.*" (source: [Resolve Billing Issues](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/resolve-issues#resolving_declined_payments)) Although, this only occurs if the billing issues (such as a declining card) occur longer than usual.